# persistent error - unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I was given a query that's running out of space in the TEMP tablespace. (see error-message below) As a quick solution to get the user back up and running, I simply added a TEMPFILE to the tablespace. (see alter statement below)  But, when I ran the query again, it still ran out of space. I can see from querying dba_temp_files that the tablespace is pretty big, and it does contain both datafiles, but I thought the MAXSIZE UNLIMITED clause would have solved my problem by not allowing the new datafile to run out of space.

Besides rewriting the query, what would you recommend?

Thanks!
Dave

```
SQL Error: ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP
01652. 00000 -  "unable to extend temp segment by %s in tablespace %s"
*Cause:    Failed to allocate an extent of the required number of blocks for
           a temporary segment in the tablespace indicated.
*Action:   Use ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE statement to add one or more
           files to the tablespace indicated.

ALTER TABLESPACE temp
  ADD TEMPFILE '+DATAC1/cop3/tempfile/temp01.dbf' SIZE 10g
  AUTOEXTEND ON
  NEXT 1g
  MAXSIZE UNLIMITED;

SQL> SELECT substr(tablespace_name,1,4) as tbls,
  2         substr(file_name,1,40) as file_name,
  3         bytes/1000000000 as gigabytes
  4    FROM dba_temp_files
  5   WHERE tablespace_name = 'TEMP'
  6  ;

TBLS FILE_NAME                                 GIGABYTES
---- ---------------------------------------- ----------
TEMP +DATAC1/cop3/tempfile/temp.771.915115045 21.4748365
TEMP +DATAC1/cop3/tempfile/temp01.dbf          34.359722
```

Comment: You’re still restricted by the amount of physical disk space availble to ASM. Have you reached that limit, perhaps?

Comment: it's better to understand the drawbacks of your query rather than adding tempfile. As an example, Is it a select statement for a huge table with order clause ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I agree with you wholeheartedly, but I was given the query by another party. So, I'd like to solve their immediate problem before having to convince them  to rewrite the query.

Comment: Thanks, Barbaros. Spurred on by your comment, I decided to spend time optimizing the query, and I've now got it executing quickly ... and using FAR less temporary storage.